# LocationListener.onLocationChanged not called for Oreo Device

Tags: google-play-services, android-location, locationlistener, android-fusedlocation, google-location-services

Callback method `LocationListener.onLocationChanged()` not called in the Oreo devices and on devices below Oreo it's working fine.

Is this coming due to using of deprecated class `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi`?

Comment: Do u want Latitude and Longitude values in Oreo?

Comment: @Shakti Bansal Have you found any solution?